# Problem with plane and angles

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I have the non coplanar straight lines that touch in (1, -2, 3):

$$L1: \frac{x - 1}{2} = \frac{y + 2}{2} = \frac{z - 3}{1}$$

$$L2: \frac{x - 1}{3} = \frac{3 - z}{-4}; y = -2$$

$$L3: \frac{x - 1}{2} = \frac{y + 2}{1} = \frac{z - 3}{2}$$

Get the equation of the plane that pass through A(-4, 2, 6) and forms equal angles with these straight lines.

What i have done was get the parametric equations:
L1:
$$x1 = 1 + 2n$$
$$y1 = -2 + 2n$$
$$z1 = 3 + n$$

L2:
$$x2 = 1 + 3n$$
$$y2 = -2$$
$$z2 = 3 + 4n$$

L3:
$$x2 = 1 + 2n$$
$$y2 = -2 + n$$
$$z2 = 3 + 2n$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(1,-2,3)$ doesn't seem to work for any of the lines in their non-parametric form since they all give something non-zero equals zero.

Comment: Oops, you are right, fixed. It was a typo

Comment: Do you know how to find the angle formed by a line and a plane?

Comment: Yes sinx = |N . L| / ||N||.||L||

Comment: But the problem gets really huge if i use this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the normal vector of the plane be $\vec{n} = \langle a,b,c \rangle$. We are told that this plane will form the same angle with all $3$ lines. Thus $\sin \theta_1 = \sin \theta_2 = \sin \theta_3$ for the lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$. This means that

$$\dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_1}|}{||\vec{n}||\cdot ||\vec{n}_{L_1}||} = \dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_2}|}{||\vec{n}||\cdot ||\vec{n}_{L_2}||} = \dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_3}|}{||\vec{n}||\cdot ||\vec{n}_{L_3}||}.$$

Since all the part contain $||\vec{n}||$ in the denominators, we can multiply everything by this and simplify the equation to

$$\dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_1}|}{||\vec{n}_{L_1}||} = \dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_2}|}{||\vec{n}_{L_2}||} = \dfrac{|\vec{n}.\vec{n}_{L_3}|}{||\vec{n}_{L_3}||}.$$

Evaluating this gives the equations

$$\dfrac{2a+2b+c}{3} = \dfrac{3a+4c}{5} = \dfrac{2a+b+2c}{3}.$$

Using the first and last piece gives
$$\dfrac{1a+2b+c}{3} = \dfrac{2a+b+2c}{3} \Longrightarrow b=c.$$

Using the first and second piece gives
$$\dfrac{2a+2b+c}{3} = \dfrac{3a+4c}{5} \Longrightarrow a=-3b.$$

So we have that $\vec{n} = \langle -3b, b, b \rangle$. Pick any value for $b$, say $1$. So $\vec{n} = \langle -3,1,1 \rangle$.  Using this and the given point, define the equation for the plane.

Comment: Thanks, i was doing it wrong. I was taking everything, not only the n part. But i understand. Thanks